# Assumptions for simple linear regression

Tags: diagrams

I would like to plot the below graph in latex. How would I do that?[image]

Comment: I'd recommend TikZ for this. TeXample.net has some stats-related [examples](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/plotting/).